# Show payment child html form based on payment selection

Tags: checkout, payment

I'm adding payment information section in custom theme. I've update [chechout phtml code](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70835/show-html-of-selected-payment-method-in-payment-information) and All enabled payment methods are visible in payment information section.

[image]

I've my template code referenced from app/design/frontend/base/default/teplate/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml file. I'm overwriting block Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container.In my console I see error `Uncaught ReferenceError: payment is not defined` due to `payment.init();` line in

```
   <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('scripts'); ?>
    payment.init();
    <?php if (is_string($oneMethod)): ?>
    payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $oneMethod ?>');
        <?php endif; ?>
    //]]>
```

On clicking on any particular payment method I want to load it's corresponding child html. but onclick of `payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $oneMethod ?>');` the corresponding child form is not being loaded. What I need to do to load corresponding child html of any payment method given that I'm not using Magento default theme?

I'm not getting form html from my block function which is defined as

```
   public function getPaymentMethodFormHtml(Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract $method)
    {
         return $this->getChildHtml('payment.method.' . $method->getCode());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my console I see error Uncaught ReferenceError: payment is not
>   defined due to payment.init();

It looks like you need to check if the following source code is present when you open your checkout page:

```
var payment = new Payment('co-payment-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/savePayment') ?>');
```

You can't switch payment method because javascript object "payment" is not initialised. So that is why `payment.init()` gives you an error.
Also please make sure that opcheckout.js script is loaded, because it contains the "Payment" class.
When you get it fixed, we can move on further.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to load fields for selected payment. Basically to load child `html` for payment method, it is done from `.php` file.

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Block_Form_Pay extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('pay/form/pay.phtml');
    }
}
```

This is explained [here](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/28/magento-create-custom-payment-method) step by step.

Check each part thoroughly.

Comment: Adarsh, yes I want to show fields for selected payment. But I'm not developing custom field/template. I want to show available fields say I've selected Credit Card(Saved) so the corresponding template should automatically load which is present with default magento.

Comment: Can you provide your link? If you have it live.

Comment: Sorry, I'm developing it on my local system. Here you can see my phtml code where I'm echoing all active payment methods http://pastebin.com/qf3JVBD7

Comment: Can you replace this line `$methods = Mage::getModel('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();` with `$methods = $this->getMethods();`.

Comment: It's not returning any value if I'm adding that. It is not able to find getMethods() function as it's not present in my custom payment module.

Comment: When looking in to latest magento files, that's all different I could find, I would suggest to replace fresh files again and see if default functions are working at least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24749/discussion-between-amitshree-and-adarsh-khatri).